# Json to fill Dual ListBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

Im working with a dual listbox control from http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/ and am trying to populate it with information that comes back from a JSON request.

Initially I was populating the Duallistbox with a sub in VB like this

```
Public Shared Sub GenerateDropDownListAndValues(dt As DataTable, ddl As DropDownList, addSelect As Boolean)

    ddl.DataSource = dt
    ddl.DataTextField = dt.Columns(1).ToString()
    ddl.DataValueField = dt.Columns(0).ToString()
    ddl.DataBind()
    If addSelect = True Then
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please select"))
    End If

End Sub
```

and then with the JQuery using this

```
$('#MainContent_ddlUnassignedFiles').bootstrapDualListbox(
        {
            nonSelectedListLabel: 'Non-selected',
            selectedListLabel: 'Selected',
            preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
            moveOnSelect: true
        });
```

on page load and postback this works fine, populates no problem.

However, when I ajax to populate the DLB I get nothing back

this is the ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Assignments.aspx/GetIncompleteSpreadsheets",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#MainContent_ddlUnassignedFiles").select2("destroy");

            var ddlUnassignedFiles = $("#MainContent_ddlUnassignedFiles");
            ddlUnassignedFiles.empty();
            $.each(data.d, function () {
                ddlUnassignedFiles.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
            $("#MainContent_ddlUnassignedFiles").select2();

            $("#saveModal").modal("hide");

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error :" + data);
            console.log(data);
            $("#saveModal").modal("hide");
        }
    });
```

and this is the call that's providing the json \ response

```
    <Script.Services.ScriptMethod(), Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetIncompleteSpreadsheets(val As Integer) As List(Of ListItem)
    Dim listOfParam As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    Dim userIdParam As New SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    userIdParam.Value = GetUserId()
    listOfParam.Add(userIdParam)

    Dim groupParam As New SqlParameter("@GroupId", SqlDbType.Int)
    groupParam.Value = val
    listOfParam.Add(groupParam)

    Dim dt = GetDataAsDatatable(listOfParam, ConnStr, "App.usp_GetAssignedLists")

    Dim retVal = (From row As Object In dt.Rows Select New ListItem() With {
        .Value = row("RequestHeaderId"),
    .Text = row("FileName")}).ToList()

    Return retVal
End Function
```

The question I have here is when using the same code to fill another drop down list, this works perfectly. However the problem I have is that the DLB is not being filled, but another drop down list is being created on the page and not populating the right control.

Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me:

**HTML: Update**

```
<select id="test">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
```

**JS: Update**

```
$("#test").bootstrapDualListbox();

$.getJSON("/api/Home/").success(function (array) {
    $("#test").children().remove();
    $.each(array, function () {
        $('<option>').text(this).appendTo("#test");
    })

    $("#test").bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
})
```

**My controller method (C#):**

```
public List<int> Get()
{
    return new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
}
```

**Result:**

[image: duallistboxresult]

Comment: I get the first set of results back no problem now, but the issue I have now is if the list needs to change, it doesn't destroy \ rebuild the data

Comment: I updated the answer. The select element starts with two options (A and B). In the ajax callback, these options are replaced with the new options, and the DLB is refreshed.

Comment: thank you for the response, I will try again shortly.

Comment: sorry, didn't get chance to try, had a power outage and then had to recover a few systems in the office and then forgot.  Will try it now and come back to you

Comment: Yes, it was the refresh that i was missing.